# How to check whether an UITextfield is entered with data or not?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

what is the default value of an uitextfield?
I need to implement a login page alert with message" please enter both the fields"
How to implement the check condition whether username and password textfields are filled ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your login view will have a Username(**txtUsername**) and a Password(**txtPwd**) text fields. And a button(**btnLogin**).

```
-(IBAction)Login:id(sender)  
{
if([txtUsername.text length] !=0 && [txtPwd.text length] !=0)
{
// Navigate to view controller you want to
}
else
{
UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"please enter both the fields" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alertView show];                           
[alertView release];
}
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

        //OK clicked

        //Do something

    } 
    else {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check when enter/return/done is pressed on keyboard using
textFieldShouldReturn delegate..

[textFieldShouldReturn:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

If you want to check while user is typing itself, you can use

> textFieldDidBeginEditing

and

> textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

Read [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) documentation...

Answer (score 1):

You can check length of entered text. For example:

```
if ([usernameTextField.text length] == 0 && [passwordTextField.text length] == 0) {
      // inform user to enter both data
}
```